# %-d flag with specifier not working

Tags: perl, strftime

My platform is Linux. I want the printed date to be formatted as `Apr 3, 2014, 5:28 PM` when given input such as `2014-04-03T17:28:54.864Z`.

My current Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib '/tmp/DateTime/Format';
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
my $date = "2014-04-03T17:28:54.864Z";
my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601 -> new;
my $dt = $iso8601->parse_datetime( $date );
print "Date before conversion *******-> \"$date\"\n";

my $s6 = $dt->strftime("%b %-d, %Y, %I:%M %p");
print "Date after conversion *******-> \"$s6\"\n";
```

It gives the output `Apr %-d, 2014, 05:28 PM`. When the day of the month or hour is a single digit, I do not want zero or space padding. I want the output as `Apr 3, 2014, 5:28 PM` when day and hour are each a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

I see no `%-d` option listed in the [valid `strftime` patterns](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm#strftime_Patterns).

You could use `%e` to get a leading space instead of a leading zero but, since you discount that, you can get the day independently, then change it and use that changed value within the format string, something like (untested, but you'll get the idea):

```
# Get day and remove leading zero.

my $dayofmonth = $dt->strftime("%d");
$dayofmonth =~ s/^0//;

# Construct format string from "hard-coded" day.

my $s6 = $dt->strftime("%b " . $dayofmonth . ", %Y, %I:%M %p");
```

Comment: I told i dont want the leading space also in case when day is single digit (1-9). How can I get that?Also, I want the same in case of hour value.Please suggest

Comment: @user3616128, that would be covered by the _second_ half of that sentence, had you bothered to read it. I've now posted some sample code which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $s6 = $dt->format_cldr('MMM d, Y, h:mm a');
```

It makes use of the module:

DateTime::Format::CLDR - Parse and format CLDR time patterns

Which you can find documented [here](http://search.cpan.org/~maros/DateTime-Format-CLDR-1.13/lib/DateTime/Format/CLDR.pm).

Answer (score 0):

Because there aren't any [`strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm#strftime_Patterns) patterns for days other than `%d` and `%e`, the easy solution is just to edit the result after the fact

```
$s6 =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

This would change your script to the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $date = "2014-04-03T17:28:54.864Z";
my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;
my $dt = $iso8601->parse_datetime( $date );
print qq{Date before conversion *******-> "$date"\n};

my $s6 = $dt->strftime("%b %e, %Y, %I:%M %p");
$s6 =~ s/\s+/ /g;
print qq{Date after conversion *******-> "$s6"\n};
```